# Compare Number of File in a Library Folder to Number on a List

Tags: 2013, list

Im looking to create the ability to compare the number of files in a document library folder to a number in a SharePoint list.

For Example a SharePoint list has ClientA with a **# of files to be uploaded** at 5 each week. I want to create a way for the ClientA folder in the library to send a workflow notification each night until the all 5 files are uploaded for that week. Im good with the workflow portion Im just unsure of how to create the functionality for folder ClientA to identify with the list item named ClientA AND then read the # of files to be uploaded.

Comment: If you're going to do it once per night, why you need a workflow? Make a console application + SCOM and a schedule task.